# $('#details').change() doesn't execute function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net

I have the following code:

```
$('#details').on('change', (e) => {
console.log('change detected');
$('#details').find('*').attr('disabled', true);
$.ajax({
   //...
});


function ResetFilters() {
    $('#Neighbourhoods')[0].selectedIndex = 0;
    $('#LowestPrice')[0].value = 0;
    $('#HighestPrice')[0].value = 999;
    $('#LowestReviews')[0].value = 0;
    $('#HighestReviews')[0].value = 10;

    $('#details').change();
}
```

Unfortunately the **$('#details').change();** doesn't execute the onchange method defined above.

I have also tried the **$('#details').trigger('change');** But that didn't work either.

Does anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Any suggestions are welcome.

EDIT:

here is my html (Im using asp.net)

```
@model AirBnB.ViewModels.ListingsViewModel

@await Html.PartialAsync("City", Model.Details)

<hr/>

<h4>Filters</h4>
<form action="/" method="post" id="details" class="details-block">
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Neighbourhoods", Model.Details)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Prices", Model.Details)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("Reviews", Model.Details)
    @await Html.PartialAsync("ResetFilters")
</form>

<script src="~/js/filter.js" asp-append-version="true"></script>

<hr/>

@await Html.PartialAsync("Charts")
```

Comment: Please post your html

Comment: Why do you have all those statement labels in the `ResetFilter()` function? You never use the for anything.

Comment: Where are you calling `ResetFilters()`?

Comment: Why are you mixing jQuery and ordinary JS syntax like that? Just write `$("#LowestPrice").val(0)`.

Comment: @azeós in a button onclick, I've verified that the resetfunction gets called

Answer (score 1):

details is a form, perhaps you meant

```
$('#details').on('submit', (e) => {
console.log('change detected');
$('#details').find('*').attr('disabled', true);
$.ajax({
   //...
});
```